# Mean amount of observations on specific time-periods different per id

Tags: r, grouping

I have two data frames,

the first [pocket_money] contains a column with ids and a column with dates and a row specifies that the person associated with the id received pocket money on that date.

the second [burgers] contains an overview of how many burgers some id has eaten in the time between the last observation and the next one (a week)

I am looking for a way in which I can create a list [out] where for each id the mean amount of burgers eaten until/between/after each time someone got pocket money.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(88)

n = 2
events = 4
period = 6
max_obs = 50

pocket_money <- 
  data.frame(id = sample(1:n, events, replace = TRUE), 
                date = sample(lubridate::today() - weeks(2:(period - 1)), events, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(id, date) %>%
  distinct
  
burgers <- 
  expand.grid(id = 1:n, date = lubridate::today() - weeks(1:period)) %>%
  mutate(obs = sample(0:max_obs, nrow(.), replace = TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(id, date)

out <- list("1" = c(mean(c(6,9,8)), 14, 28, 24),
       "2" = c(mean(c(32, 45, 31, 20, 1)), 15))
```

Comment: not clear to me.. how do you define `until/between/after each time someone got pocket money` ?